# How can I swap the SQLite file in OrmLite?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I have an android application that relies on a sqlite database, and use OrmLite to access my DB.

Instead of OrmLite creating the tables I rely on downloading the database from a central server as the user will often want to "sync" things. Currently I don't have the fancy sync code written so the app replaces the db. The steps are:

1 Download the latest SQLite db file from the server, as a zip
2 Expand the file to produce a database.sqlite file in a temporary folder
3 Deletes the contents of a data folder, which contains the live database.sqlite file
4 Move the database.sqlite file from the temporary folder to the data folder.

The problem is that the new database file seems to get ignored and DAO queries I run return old data. The only way to show data from the new version of the DB is to restart the application.

To test things I created a table with a timestamp that records when the database was generated, each time you request a new copy of the sqlite db from the server this is updated. I have a fragment that displays this time so you know how fresh your data is. In the fragments onResume method I make a call to the DAO to get the timestamp and put value on screen. I've stepped through this and I see the call to the DAO but the value that comes back is from the old, now deleted, db. Restart the app and the correct value is shown.

So my question is, if I replace the underlying sqlite db file that stores my database, how can I tell ormlite to pick it up or refresh the connection or whatever it has to do???

I tried calling clearObjectCache on the DAO, made no difference.

Comment: `Currently I don't have the fancy sync code written so the app replaces the db.` - are you sure that you want to put that much effort into a hackish workaround if you have to write the sync code anyways?

Comment: The sync code relies on a large piece of work that will happen later as its a complex db. As the db zips down relatively small then just grabbing the latest copy and swapping it into place is fine as the android app will always be read only.